# Can you rename replication jobs?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have snapshot replication running on three different servers, two publishers and one subscriber.  The replication processes have associated jobs (either building the snap shot or grabbing the snap shot, I believe) that have ugly system-generated names.  Is it safe to rename these something that's readable and understandable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can rename the jobs.  They will still function normally because they are identified by job_id for system purposes.

You can find more info about how it is uses in the MSdistribution_agents table.  More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174399(v=sql.90).aspx